# Correction variance estimation from the posterior in a Bayesian framework

Tags: bayesian, variance, posterior

My question is quite basic, I have posterior distributions for some parameters derived from an arbitrary Bayesian framework. Since I know that the posterior variance under-estimates the true variance, what types of correction are available in order to have better inferences ?

I more interested in general methods/frameworks than problem specific solutions.

Any insight will be appreciated.